# Force rendering mode in IE7 without doctype switching?

Tags: internet-explorer, rendering, doctype

I'm developing a portlet application where I cannot control the doctype. I need to put IE7 in standard mode for things to work. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard mode"? Do you mean strict (standardised) HTMLx.x?

Comment: yes. standard compliance mode